# How to toggle the transparency view on edge selected mode in Blender 2.80?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface, edit-mode

The edge selection lines/outlines are partially obscuring part of the mesh I'm working on, so I would like to be able to make these lines more transparent as to more easily see what I'm working on without zooming in excessively.

(I'm using 2.8 beta)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use toggle x-ray option:

[image: xray]

Available both in wire-frame and solid view with option:

[image: xray option]